# Partial Fraction Decomposition with Exponents

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

I want to break this fraction into two parts:
$$\frac{5^n3^n}{(5^n-3^n)(5^{n+1}-3^{n+1})}$$
when I try to equate this to:
$$\frac{A}{(5^n-3^n)} - \frac{B}{(5^{n+1}-3^{n+1})} $$
I get the value of A by substituting the value of n by 0:
$$A(5^{0+1}-3^{0+1}) = 5^03^0 $$
$$ A= \frac{1}{2} $$
Similarly the value of B is -0.5

By another method when I try to find the value of A and B
$$5^n(5A + B) - 3^n(3A+B) = 5^n3^n$$
and then solving for 5A+B = 3^n and 3A + B = 0
I get the value of:
$$A = \frac{3^n}{2}$$
$$B = -\frac{3^{n+1}}{2}$$

I can't understand why both methods give different values and why the first one is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial fractions is for rational functions of a variable $x$, and what you have is not a rational function of $n$.
The methods that work for rational functions should not be expected to work here.

If you want to write
$$ \frac{5^n 3^n}{(5^n- 3^n)(5^{n+1}-3^{n+1})} = \frac{A}{5^n - 3^n} - \frac{B}{5^{n+1}-3^{n+1}}$$
(presumably when the none of the denominators are $0$),
that is equivalent to 
$$ 5^n 3^n = (5^{n+1}-3^{n+1}) A - (5^n-3^n) B $$
Now there are certainly no solutions where $A$ and $B$ are constants.   A solution where $A$ and $B$ are multiples of $3^n$ is $A= 3^n/2$, $B = 3^{n+1}/2$.  A solution where 
$A$ and $B$ are multiples of $5^n$ is $A = 5^n/2$, $B = 5^{n+1}/2$.
Or you could take a combination of these solutions:

$$ A = \frac{5^n}{2} t + \frac{3^n}{2} (1-t),\ B = \frac{5^{n+1}}{2} t + \frac{3^{n+1}}{2} (1-t) $$

where $t$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

$n=0$ is not the case you want to work with.  $5^0=3^0=1$.  Therefore

$\displaystyle \frac{A}{(5^0 - 3^0)} = $???

Note that if you solve for any particular $n$ (other than zero) you will get results that are correct *for that particular* $n$, but not correct for the general problem.